# String uri to open a page in facebook lite app

Tags: android, facebook

When I wanna open a page on normal facebook app (calling it through my app) I use the follow string to make the Uri.parse().
`"fb://page/[pageId]"`, and it works normally
I do this:

```
String uriStr = "fb://page/[pageId]";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriStr);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

However when I try open it in facebook lite, the same doesn't work, and my app is closed by some error. :( Exist another way? What is the correct string to open the same page in facebook lite? Anyone knows? Thx

**EDIT**

LogCat error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
```

Comment: *my app is closed by some error* - What is the error? Post the error logcat.

Comment: @Prerak Sola Thx, `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent`, I edited there too.

Answer (score 2):

`int versionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.lite", 0).versionCode;
                            if (versionCode >= 3002850) { //newer versions osf fb app
                                link = "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + FACEBOOK_URL;
                            } else { //older versions of fb app
                                link = "fb://page/" + FACEBOOK_URL;
                            }`}

Comment: Thx, but had a same problem `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent`

Answer (score 0):

```
uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + url);

new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```

Comment: Thx, but this return the same error `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent`, just to be sure that I did the right thing, this url that you said is the HTTP one, right? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Look like this

```
String uri = "facebook://facebook.com/inbox";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

or for special activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

hope it help.

Comment: Hi, really thx for your help, in this first case( "facebook://facebook.com/inbox") where I inform my pageId? 'cause I'm trying to do a button to user visite my page.