# How can I open a link with the Facebook app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to open a Facebook search link `https://m.facebook.com/search/people/?q=Name` in `Xamarin.Forms` with the `Facebook app` or the `Facebook Lite app` (whichever the user has installed) or with the default browser if no relevant app is installed that works with both Android and iOS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open Facebook / Twitter app from my iOS app in Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456618/how-to-open-facebook-twitter-app-from-my-ios-app-in-xamarin)

Comment: Maybe partially. The first part of my question though is which which URL should I try to open with the Facebook apps. Should I try to open this one `https://m.facebook.com/search/people/?q=Name` or should I modify it?

Comment: Please take a look more accurate on a link that @Shaw mentioned. You should use `Launcher.TryOpenAsync("fb://{some_data})`. If it returns false, then Facebook app not installed and you need to open your link `https://m.facebook.com/search/people/?q=Name` via browser

Comment: @choper
In case the Facebook app (or the Facebook Lite app) is installed which link should I open with them?

Comment: Check the [latest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67653826/10366303), not tested, but not the accepted one in the question I mentioned. About the search link, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app) might help?

Comment: @Shaw The method for detecting if one of the apps is installed works fine. The URL I use is `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/search/people/?q=Name`. It works for the `Facebook app` but not for the `Facebook Lite app`. Is there any official documentation about the URL schemes the Facebook apps use?

Comment: Do not find the official documents for that. Maybe the link below would be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277564/string-uri-to-open-a-page-in-facebook-lite-app

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT 
Well, that must be outdated because the proposed solution `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + FACEBOOK_URL` does not work for me with the latest version of `Facebook Lite`.

Comment: @choper
Is there a way to make the method of detection work only with Facebook app, since `Facebook Lite` does not support opening the same link? In case a user has only `Facebook Lite` installed then the browser should be used instead.

Comment: @Costas For now, i still have not find the url for Facebook Lite app.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I haven't either. Is there a way though to modify the check proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67653826/7360423 in order to open the URL with the default browser when an attempt to open it with Facebook Lite takes place?

Comment: hhh. Let's try it.